# Getting user info in google drive sdk

Tags: email, oauth, permissions, google-drive-api, scopes

I am using this three scopes:

```
            scopes[0] = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
            scopes[1] = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
            scopes[2] = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
```

Authorizing them, and then trying to get user's email address according to:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list
By doing:

```
            PermissionList permissions = _service.Permissions.List("root").Fetch();
            IList<Permission> a = permissions.Items;
```

And I don't see the emailAddress.
When I'm including the same scopes (even only the first two) at the "Try it!" section,
I get a result including the emailAddress

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the email of the authorizing user, try the tokeninfo endpoint (which you should be calling anyway for security purposes). See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#obtaininguserprofileinformation

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but just by the way you have referenced the scopes e.g. `scopes[0], scopes[1], scopes[2]`. It looks like  you are storing them in an array.

When I was retrieving user info using the client side (javascript) oauth, they were simply space delimited.

Answer (score 0):

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
```

To add multiple scopes, add a whitespace in between the scopes.